# GSON StackOverFlow Error- Serialization when using Lombok with Inheritance

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, java-8, lombok

I have a POJO that extends another class ParentDTO both using Lombok with builder Pattern 
ChildDTO

```
@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class ChildDTO extends ParentDTO {
    private final Foo foo; // Foo also extends ParentDTO

    @Singular("items")
    private final List<Item> items;      
}
```

ParentDTO

```
@Data       
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true) 
public abstract class ParentDTO implements Serializable {  

    @JsonIgnore private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();  

    protected ParentDTO () {} 

}
```

My Code Implementation(here I am getting error in gson.toJson)

```
  @PostMapping("/sendRequest")
  public ResponseEntity<String> sendMessage(@RequestBody ChildDTO payload) {

 final ChildDTO childDTO = payload.toBuilder().bar("xyz").build();
 String serializedData = gson.toJson(childDTO); //getting stackoverflow exception in this line.
 publishMesaage(serializedData);
    
    
return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
```

}

I am seeing the  stackoverflow error happening in line gson.toJson(childDTO)  when trying to use Gson.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError        
        at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
        at java.lang.String.getChars(String.java:826)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:449)
        at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:270)
        at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:112)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:590)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:401)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beginObject(JsonWriter.java:308)
        at
```

Comment: You are mixing Gson and Jackson in your example. Please boil it down to a minimal example without the confusing Jackson stuff.

Comment: I don’t understand what you meant.I just have two Pojo’s and I am trying to use Gson.toJson

Comment: This part of code was working before but when I extended ChildDto class with the ParentDTO it started giving stackoverflow error.                String serializedData = gson.toJson(childDTO);

Comment: There are several things in your code that don't add up: `@JsonIgnore` and `ObjectMapper` are Jackson-specific, but you use Gson. Furthermore, the `ParentDTO` constructor does nothing (because it just creates a local variable). Reduce your code to a minimal example that triggers the exception.

Comment: Please check the code and the method(sendMessage) where I am getting the stackoverflow error.

Comment: what is `ObjectMapper` doing in DTO?